# Can't scroll down to the last item in the ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a `ListView` using custom class named `ListViewCustomAdapter` that extends `BaseAdapter` class. In each row of `ListView`, i am displaying student information like name, id etc...

**Problem:**

Here's a visual presentation of my problem

When i add three students, they fit completely on the screen

[image]

**Now** when i add the 4th student and try to scroll down to view the 4th student, screen only scrolls down to half of the 4th student's information

[image]

**Any idea what's causing this issue and how can i fix this ?**

Here's my `getView` method implemented in my custom class

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.listview_custom_adapter_row_layout, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
            holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameLabel2);
            holder.age = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ageLabel2);
            holder.ID = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.IDLabel2);
            holder.degree = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.degreeLabel2);
            holder.email = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.emailLabel2);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        Student stu = studentList.get(position);
        holder.img.setImageResource(stu.getProfilePicID());
        holder.name.setText(stu.getStudentName());
        holder.age.setText(stu.getStudentAge());
        holder.ID.setText(stu.getStudentID());
        holder.degree.setText(stu.getStudentDegree());
        holder.email.setText(stu.getStudentEmail());

        return convertView;
}
```

**listview_custom_adapter_row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/student_profile_pic"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:text="Name: "
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/nameLabel2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ageLabel"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Age: "
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/ageLabel2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/IDLabel"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="ID: "
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ageLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/IDLabel2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/degreeLabel"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Degree: "
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/IDLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/degreeLabel2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailLabel"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Email: "
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/degreeLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/emailLabel2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameLabel2"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/nameLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ageLabel2"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/nameLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameLabel2"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/IDLabel2"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/nameLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ageLabel2"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/degreeLabel2"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/nameLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/IDLabel2"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailLabel2"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/nameLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/degreeLabel2"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"/>

    <!--just to add margin at the bottom of each row-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailLabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_custom_adapter_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.yousaf.listview_customadapter.CustomAdapterMain">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pageHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Student Information"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/studentInfoList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pageHeading"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:dividerHeight="7dp">
    </ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the content of `listview_custom_adapter_row_layout.xml`

Comment: @szamani20 added ..

Comment: I think you have issue with `listView` xml can you provide it? the main layout

Comment: @Ibrahim done....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `25dp` margins for `listView`, setting `15dp` to your `textView` `android:layout_marginTop="15dp"` and `10dp` to your `listView`.

By making your `listView` at the bottom of your `textView` `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pageHeading"`

That's adding `15dp` + `10dp`.

There is many tricks to avoid that:

- Add margin bottom to `listView` `25dp`
- remove unimportant margins
- Add bottom padding to your main layout

You handle it on your own.

Your layout should be like:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pageHeading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Student Information"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/studentInfoList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pageHeading"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:dividerHeight="7dp">
    </ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: adding `marginBottom` to `listview` solves the issue but to add `marginBottom`, i have to set `constraintBottom_toBottomOf= parent` of `listview`. If i do this, `pageHeading` and `listview` overlap each other. How can i avoid this ?

Comment: You can add  bottom `padding` to the parent layout, i think it's best solution for your case, BTW using recycleview is more better.

Comment: @Yousaf also you can use a `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"` on your list view.

Comment: I have fixed it using nested layout... anyways thanks for your answer, it definitely solved the main issue.

Comment: @Yousaf with constraintLayout you don't need that specially with this simple layout, check edit.

Answer (score 0):

Set layout_height match_constraint

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set `layout_constrainedHeight` to **true**